# Does Windows authentication provide non-repudiation?

Tags: wcf, windows-authentication

I've been searching for a bit now, but I can't find an answer.  [WCF Security Best Practices](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/WCF_Security_Best_Practices) say to use Windows Authentication when possible.  Can this provide non-repudiation and data integrity if you require signing?

(The most important question here is non-repudiation.  I'm using TLS but trying to determine if I can provide non-repudiation through Windows Auth with TLS or MLS.  Theoretically, the TLS provides hop-to-hop data integrity.)

Comment: The clue is in the question - authentication is orthogonal from non-repudiation and data integrity (which are also mutually orthogonal).

Comment: @syncbean - **if you require signing**, which is where all of this would come in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for first question. Check this:

[Chapter 4: WCF Security Fundamentals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650862.aspx)

Windows Authentication does not provide data signing.

Comment: I was on this page earlier today - where does it say that Windows Auth provides non-repudiation?  Also, how can it do so if it doesn't sign the message?

Comment: It uses a token which is a hash of machinename, user and password, this hash is trusted by a third part server, the domain controller. If you want to prevent in transit modification of the content, you should use SSL, I'm not sure if in transit modification of the content will invalidate the token, I think not.

Comment: I was on that page earlier, and I don't see where it states that this provides non-repudiation. If the message isn't signed, how can it provide non-repudation for the message?

Comment: According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650619.aspx#Step2), the wsHttpBinding uses Windows Auth and MLS by default, and MLS is used to encrypt and sign messages.  It doesn't so far as to say that Windows Auth will let you sign the message, though..

Answer (score 0):

Windows Authentication is preferrable and suggested by the best practice guide because it is built in all Microsoft machines.  It doesn't like the certificate that requires a lot of infrastructure setup.  If your machine is joined to an Active Directory domain, it should just work.

Windows Authentication is using [SPNEGO](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4178) to negotiate to use which authentication method, *Kerberos* or *NTLM*.  Whenever possible, client and server will try to pick *Kerberos* first.  Otherwise, *NTLM* will be used.

To answer your question of whether the message can be sigend or not, both *Kerberos* and *NTLM* can be used to **sign** and **encrypt** messages.  As a WCF programmer, it should be transparent to you.  All you need to do is to set the [ProtectedLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347692.aspx) to EncryptAndSign.  If you don't believe me, you can look at the network trace after setting up the Windows Authentication.  You should see the messages are encrypted.

When using the Windows Authentication, WCF will call SSPI to do authentication and message encryption.  I won't cover the detials of SSPI.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375388(v=vs.85).aspx) is the SSPI call for *NTLM* to encrypt message and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375385(v=vs.85).aspx) is the SSPI call for *Kerberos* to encrypt message.  You can set a break point in Windbg to prove that.

Although it's not explicitly stated in the above links, [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995352.aspx) clearly states that the above mentioned EncryptMessages methods can provide data integrity (*signing*) and privacy (*encryption*).

Back to your original question about whether Windows authentication support `non-repudiation`, this is actually a bigger question.  *Data signing* is necessary for `non-repudiation` but not sufficient.  WCF is also providing the auditing feature to record operation or transaction.  This is to guarantee that a user cannot deny performing an operation or initiating a transaction.  So, in order to support `non-repudiation`, you should also set [SuppressAuditFailure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicesecurityauditbehavior.suppressauditfailure(VS.85).aspx) to false to make sure auditing is always functioning properly.

Comment: Would we have enough visibility into the GSS_Unwrap call to pull the user out of the transaction?  The encryption has to be handled in TLS; we would probably want the signing to occur in MLS so that we can get at it at the service level, right?